# Should I make an API for users and an API for admins?

Tags: python, rest, falconframework

I'm having a little trouble figuring out if I should have an API for admins and for users splitted. So:

Admins should login using /admin/login with a POST request, and users just /login.
Admins should access/edit/etc resources on /admin/resourceName and users just /resourceName.

Comment: Should -> opinion based. Not good for SO.

Comment: In my personal opinion, you should use the API key to control who is admin and who is not. Someone hitting `/login` using an admin key will login as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have one endpoint, not one for each type of user. What if you have moderators? Will you also create a /mods/login ?

What each user should and shouldn't have access to should be sorted out with permissions.